# Fetching Azure Subscription ID & Deployment Slot (really fast)

Tags: azure

As a follow up to my question about [Deployment Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109944/events-that-fire-when-a-hosted-services-deployment-slot-changes-swap-vip), I'd like to ask if there is a **fast way** to find:

- Current Subscription Id
- The current deployment slot the role is in (Staging/Production)

I am currently using the Management API, which is a bit slow, but I don't want to cache it for long because I can't be sure the cache will invalidate upon the slot swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a running instance, you might be able to tell if you are in staging/production from the host URL for a web role.  If you see your deployment ID there, it is staging.  However, this can get tricky if you are using CNAMEs or you are running a worker role.  For subscription ID, there is not much you can do as that is a pre-cursor to everything.  You can't even use the Mgmt API if you don't know your SubID (there is no way that I am aware of to get the subscription ID other than portal).

Seems like the management API is your best bet (and only bet in some cases).