# Detect Azure Stage or Production by Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

I know this question has been asked before, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391284/how-to-detect-if-the-environment-is-staging-or-production-in-azure-hosted-servic). But they all very old, the method is very complex and I tried cannot really get it work. So I wonder if the new Azure SDK gives something easy, I guess should from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` namespace.

I need this because I use a worker role that mount CloudDrive, keep checking it and share to the network, then build a lucene.net on it.

This deployment works very well.

Since only 1 instance can mount the CloudDrive, so when I do VIP swap, I have to stop/(or delete) the stage deployment, then the new production deployment can successfully mount the drive. This cause the fulltext search stop for awhile (around 1-2 minutes if everything well and I click the button fast enough). So I wonder if I can detect current status, and only mount when production and unmount when stage.

Comment: Nothing new has been added to the SDK since that answer was written.  The answer is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out one way to solve this, please see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138700/1424115

Answer (score 2):

Here a what more simpler solution.
What i did was an ip check. The staging enviroment gets a different external ip then the production enviroment. The production ip adres is the ip of (yourapp).cloudapp.net. So the only thing you need to do is to check if these two match.