# Prevent azure staging environment from accessing queue messages

Tags: azure, azure-storage

After swapping the latest azure deployment from staging to production, I need to prevent the staging worker role from accessing the queue messages. I can do this by detecting if the environment is staging or production in code, but can anyone tell me if there is a any other way to prevent staging environment from accessing and processing queue messages??

Thanks for the help!
Mahesh

Comment: I've answered below, but just out of curiosity, how would you detect if a given role is in staging or production in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the platform that would do this.  This is an app/code thing.  If the app has the credentials (for example, account name and key) to access the queue, then it is doing what it was coded to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have your staging environment use the primary storage key and your production environment use the secondary storage key.  When you do the VIP swap you can regenerate the storage key that your now-staging environment is using which will result in it no longer having credentials to access the queue.

Notice that this does introduce a timing issue.  If you do the swap first and then change the storage keys then you run the risk of the worker roles picking up messages in between the two operations.  If you change the keys first and then do the swap then there will be a second or two where your production service is no longer pulling messages from the queue.  It will depend on what your service does as to whether or not this timing issue is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually detect which Deployment Slot that current instance is running in.  I detailed how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138700/1424115

It's really not as easy as it should be, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question of protecting your DEV/TEST environment from your PRODUCTION environment, you may want to consider separate Azure subscriptions (one for each environment).  This guide from Patterns and Practices talks about the advantages of this approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803371.aspx#sec29

Answer (score 0):

kwill's answer of regenerating keys is a good one, but I ended up doing this:

1. Optional - stop the production worker role from listening to the queue by changing an appropriate configuration key which tells it to ignore messages, then rebooting the VM (either through the management portal or by killing the WaHostBootstrapper.exe)
2. Publish to the staged environment (this will start accessing the queue, which is fine in our case)
3. Swap staged <-> production via Azure
4. Publish again, this time to the new staged environment (old live)

You now have both production and staging worker roles running the latest version and servicing the queue(s).  This is a good thing for us, as it gives us twice the capacity, and since staging is running anyway we may as well use it!

It's important that you only use staging as a method of publishing to live (as it was intended) - create a whole new environment for testing/QA purposes, which has its own storage account and message queues.