# Need I clone an Azure storage account for staging slot?

Tags: azure, development-environment, azure-table-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web Application `myapp` that uses (via `myappConnectionString`) a Table Storage Account `mytables`.

I created two development slots for `myapp`: `myapp-dev` and `myapp-staging`. 
I've set the `myappConnectionString` as "Slot setting"...

Now, what is the option for `mytables`? 
Should I create two new storage accounts, or there is a possibility to create the "dev slots" for the `mytables`, `mytables-dev` and `mytables-staging`, then use it in the `myappConnectionString`?

Comment: Related posts - [Azure storage: staging vs . production](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12512603/465053) & [Staging or Production Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4328462/465053)

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple tables in the same storage account and then just update the connectionString to point to the correct one, like you pointed out.

However, personally, I would isolate them further and create different storage accounts where you would have the tables for each deployment slot.

Since you are only charged for how much space your tables are consuming, you are not incurring any additional cost by having them provisioned in different storage accounts.